# Python function: Sensing if invoked directly from shell or as part of an evaluated term

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

Consider some search function that looks up a value in a dictionary. When invoked directly from a Python shell, I'd like it to print some nice output to the user, but if it is called by some other function then nothing should be printed.

I found a way to achieve this with *inspect*, like this:

```
def search_for_five():
   invoked_from_interactive_shell = (inspect.stack()[1].filename == '<stdin>')
   if invoked_from_interactive_shell:
       print('Your value is 5!!!')
   else:
       return 5
```

With the above trick, calling this func from a Python shell prints a nice message, while calling it from some other function returns a value for further processing, without littering stdout.

My question is: Is there any way for me to sense a **shell** invocation that relies on the returned value for further processing?
For example, I'd like to silence the *print* call if invoked like this:

```
>>> a = search_for_five()
```

or like this:

```
>>> print(search_for_five() + 6)
11
```

but retain:

```
>>> search_for_five()
Your value is 5!!!
```

Comment: How about using different logging levels and pass a cmdline flag to specify how verbose the logging should be?

Comment: Technically, you _could_ inspect the call stack (and on a closer read I see that you're doing so), but it's a horrible idea.

Comment: People use the REPL to test what code will do when it's used in a script. When you make behavior diverge between cases, you're adding confusion for your API's users down the road. Pure functions -- ones that transform their inputs into outputs -- shouldn't have said effects at all, and if you _do_ want side effects for logging, allowing control of that is what the `logging` standard library module is for.

Comment: I think it's a horrible idea to provide a function that returns 5 under some circumstances, but `None` at other times. The whole point of the REPL is to allow quick interactive testing. I see that you realise this, since you are looking for away to avoid the damage if the function call appears in an assignment or an expression. But you only need to do that because the original idea was of questionable merit.

Comment: In complete agreement with you @BoarGules regarding the horribleness of such an implementation. Sadly, this function is added into a well established API which is used exactly like that: users might invoke the function from a prompt, or call from another function, and the way you output the result can benefit from noticing which is which. I'll probably end up wrapping one version of the function with another, but was curious if Python provides a mechanism for detecting function invocation at such fine granularity. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend changing the behavior of your function.

Instead, I would recommend creating a wrapper function that should only be used in the shell.

Something like the following:

```
def search_for_five_shell_wrapper():
    print(f'Your value is {search_for_five()}!!!')
```

Comment: As responded above, agree that there are more "correct" ways to implement this. At this point, my question is more of an exercise in Python: Could such fine-grained invocation detection be achieved, with UX correctness set aside.